# I can't assign values to the Props of the Lists I create. Reason?

Tags: c#, list, prop

```cs
public List<Musteri> musteriListesi;

public void Ekleme()
{
    int adet= 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Kaç Adet Müşteri Eklenecek?");
    adet= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    musteriListesi=Enumerable.Repeat(default(Musteri), adet).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < adet; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Müşteri Adı:");
        musteriListesi[i].Name=Console.ReadLine(); //==> Error Line
        Console.WriteLine("Müşteri Soyadı:");

        char ch;
        char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ch);
        musteriListesi[i].Gender = ch;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a date: ");
        DateTime userDateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userDateTime))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The day of the week is: " + userDateTime.DayOfWeek);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value");
        }
        musteriListesi[i].BirthDate=userDateTime;
   }
}
```

I created a List from the customer class. I try to add value to the props in the Musteri class into the List I created, but it gives an error. **customer =Musteri class**

Error Message:

> Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object.    at
> ClassMetotDemo.MusteriManager.Ekleme()

Answer (score 2):

This `default(Musteri)` evaluates to null, if `Musteri` is a reference type, it's [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values) value is null, you'll need to create a new instance of `Musteri` when you generate the `musteriListesi` list.

Replace your `Repeat` logic with:

```cs
musteriListesi = Enumerable.Range(0, adet).Select(_ => new Musteri()).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you give an example? Okay, I couldn't understand

Comment: Here is the variable that he uses as a quantity. It determines how many elements the List will have. I entered the user to be dynamic. quantity =adet

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, adet)` would create an `IEnumerable` of size `adet`, `Select` would define that each element is a new instance of `Musteri` and `ToList` would materialize it to an in-memory list (not very efficient as suggested on the other answer)

Comment: I solved my problem with adding, but running the listing method gave the same error. Can't infect the Created List? Don't know

Comment: https://gist.github.com/BarisKarapelit/dbddfb820afe2f9b55bad401b090c572

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `null` entries to your list because the `default` value of a class is `null`, not an empty object of this class. However, using `Repeat(new  Musteri(), adet)` would not solve the problem, as it would add the same object to all positions of the list, but you must create a new object for every entry.

Use the `Add` method to add entries to the list"

```cs
musteriListesi = new List<Musteri>(adet);
for (int i = 0; i < adet; i++)
{
    musteri = new Musteri();
    musteriListesi.Add(musteri);
    ...
    musteri.Name = Console.ReadLine();
    ...
}
```

Note, using the `adet` argument when creating the new list is not strictly necessary as it does not create a list of this size. It only reserves that much space in advance to the list's internal array. This makes adding entries more efficient, as the internal array will not have to be resized. If you don't know the size of the list in advance, you can just write `musteriListesi = new List<Musteri>();`.